# Check library built flags or options (-frecord-gcc-switches)

Tags: linux, gcc, dynamic-library

I'd like to check the library under investigation what flags and options were built with?

I'm trying to use gcc compiler with option `-frecord-gcc-switches` to understand on my simple shared library but with no luck.

The following is the piece of code that form a shared library :

```
#include "shared.h"
unsigned int add(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    printf("\n Inside add()\n");
    return (a+b);
}
```

shared.h looks like :

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern unsigned int add(unsigned int a, unsigned int b);
```

I run the following commands to create a shared library :

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC -frecord-gcc-switches shared.c
gcc -shared -frecord-gcc-switches -o libshared.so shared.o
```

The `readelf -n libshared.so` gives me

```
Displaying notes found in: .note.gnu.build-id
  Owner                 Data size       Description
  GNU                  0x00000014       NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
    Build ID: 8466741f5849aac95570ec68d172f9077f175f89
```

How to check what options/flag or additional libraries were used to build the resulting lib?

BTW I use

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 4):

The option `-frecord-gcc-switches` is effective only in compilation,
not in linkage, so you may omit it from:

```
$ gcc -shared -frecord-gcc-switches -o libshared.so shared.o
```

In ELF object files at least, the compilation options are written as a list of
strings into a section of the object file called `.GCC.command.line`. Default
compilation options are recorded as well those explicitly given.

If multiple object files containing this section are linked into
a shared library or program then all the input`.GCC.command.line`
sections are merged into one output section of the same name,
apparently with deduplication of the strings. So if different source
files were compiled with different options, the options that applied
to each source file may not be obvious.

To retrieve the recorded options from `libshared.so`, run:

```
$ readelf --string-dump=.GCC.command.line libshared.so
```

Output will be similar to:

```
String dump of section '.GCC.command.line':
  [     0]  -I .
  [     5]  -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu
  [    22]  -D_GNU_SOURCE
  [    30]  file1.cpp
  [    3a]  -mtune=generic
  [    49]  -march=x86-64
  [    57]  -Wextra
  [    5f]  -frecord-gcc-switches
  [    75]  -fasynchronous-unwind-tables
  [    92]  -fstack-protector-strong
  [    ab]  -Wformat
  [    b4]  -Wformat-security
  [    c6]  -fstack-clash-protection
  [    df]  -fcf-protection
  [    ef]  file2.cpp
  [    f9]  file3.cpp
  [   103]  -Wpedantic
```

Since linkage adds nothing to this information, it makes better sense to
retrieve it straight from the object files rather than the program or
shared library they are linked into:

```
$ readelf --string-dump=.GCC.command.line file.o
```

since then there can be no mistaking which compilation the
recorded options refer to.

Note this caveat in [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options)

> This switch is only implemented on some targets and the exact format of the
>   recording is target and binary file format dependent